# Protobuf-net disable seeking

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, bzip2

I am using protobuf-net in a network client/server application. Each packet of data is zipped with a BZip2Input/Output stream to compress my messages. This has worked fine for several weeks, but I have recently modified the server's objects, and am getting an exception that the BZip2Input stream does not support seeking (which it does not). I imagine this is because protobuf detects it can skip some fields, and tries to do so expediently.

Is there a way to disable this behavior, and force protobuf-net to skip fields by reading the data? (Not seeking).

Update: added the full stack trace below. Based on your comment, the stream must have a bug in it's CanSeek callback. What do you think?

```
Server First Chance Exception: BZip2InputStream Seek n
ot supported Stack Trace:    at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.BZip2.BZip2InputStream.S
eek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
Server_NewRequestReceived Exception: System.NotSupportedException: BZip2InputStream Seek not supported
   at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.BZip2.BZip2InputStream.Seek(Int64 offset, origin)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.Seek(Stream source, Int32 count, Byte[] buffer)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.SkipField()
   at proto_2(Object, ProtoReader)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSeriali    zer.Read(Object value, ProtoReader source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize(Int32 key, Object value, source)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.TryDeserializeAuxiliaryType(ProtoReader reader, format, Int32 tag, Type type, ref Object value, Boolean skipOtherFields, asListItem, Boolean autoCreate, Boolean insideList)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.TryDeserializeList(TypeModel model, ader, DataFormat format, Int32 tag, Type listType, Type itemType, ref Object value)

   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.TryDeserializeAuxiliaryType(ProtoReader reader, format, Int32 tag, Type type, ref Object value, Boolean skipOtherFields, asListItem, Boolean autoCreate, Boolean insideList)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoReader reader, Type type, value, Boolean noAutoCreate)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type, SerializationContext context)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize(Stream source)
```

---

Created this class to get around the SharpZipLib bug.

```
    public class NonSeekableStreamWrapper : Stream
    {
        public Stream BaseStream { get; private set; }

        public NonSeekableStreamWrapper(Stream baseStream)
        {
            BaseStream = baseStream;
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            BaseStream.Flush();
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            return BaseStream.Seek(offset, origin);
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            BaseStream.SetLength(value);
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            return BaseStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            BaseStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override bool CanSeek
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override long Length
        {
            get { return BaseStream.Length; }
        }

        public override long Position { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: See edit: this is definitely a bug in `BZip2InputStream`

Comment: A small thing, but it is nice to see someone who can whip up a Stream decorator without making a fuss. I would have happily added one in my answer, but just: good to see, ta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is interesting. I would be *very* interested in a full stacktrace when that happens, because AFAIK it checks the correct APIs for this, for example (from `ProtoReader.Seek`).

```
if (source.CanSeek)
{
    source.Seek(count, SeekOrigin.Current);
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ... does it the hard way, even if that means a Read loop
}
```

So no, it doesn't currently have an option for this because it *trusts the streams to tell the truth*. Of course, it could simply be a bug on my part, hence the request for a stacktrace.

If this is a genuine "thing", it would probably be possible to add such a mechanism.

---

Edit: yup, this is a bug in `BZip2InputStream.cs` in SharpZipLib; it has:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the current stream supports seeking.
    /// </summary>
    public override bool CanSeek {
        get {
            return baseStream.CanSeek;
        }
    }
```

but it also has:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Set the streams position.  This operation is not supported and will throw a NotSupportedException
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="offset">A byte offset relative to the <paramref name="origin"/> parameter.</param>
    /// <param name="origin">A value of type <see cref="SeekOrigin"/> indicating the reference point used to obtain the new position.</param>
    /// <returns>The new position of the stream.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException">Any access</exception>
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("BZip2InputStream Seek not supported");
    }
```

So, it can **never** seek, but it claims it can if the *base* stream can.

It should have reported `false` instead of echoing the base-stream's `CanSeek`.

Comment: Thanks Marc - I just submitted the issue to SharpZipLib https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/issues/11

Comment: In the meantime, I am writing a simple non seekable stream wrapper so that the CanSeek function will return false.

Comment: Yeah - I should probably just fork / fix it myself... just use their nuget package in so many projects, would like to give them a chance first.